# i cant figure out how to add images to my website from my files

Tags: html, css

I don't know why but i'm struggling so much to add images to my website.

If I have a folder called "images" on desktop with a picture called "eye"

to add that image I would have to do the following code, right?

```html
<img src="Desktop/images/eye.jpg"> ?
```

I tried

```html
<img src="Desktop/images/eye.jpg">
<img src="images/eye.jpg">
```

and tried putting in different folders and locations, but idk why it isn't working

Comment: If you are developing a website, why are the images on your desktop? Why are they not located with the HTML files?

Answer (score 1):

Put the images folders in the same working directory as your HTML project; if your images folder and HTML directory are separate, it wont work:

`<img src="images/eye.jpg" alt="images">`

Comment: Hey thanks for replying, yeah when i coding on vs it worked before, but rn i am editing on a website called dash from General assembly. and i cant add a image to a directory... 

https://dash.generalassemb.ly/projects this is the website

Comment: sorry , I am not much familiar with online HTML editor or dash

Comment: its ok, thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="images/eye.jpg" alt="Eye Image">
```

while your html file is in root folder

Answer (score 0):

To put pictures on your website, you need to tell your website where those pictures are. Here's a simple way to do it if your pictures are in a folder on your computer's desktop:

1. Folder Setup:

Make sure your website's files are organized. You should have a special folder for your website's stuff, like your web pages and pictures. For example:
markdown

```
- YourWebsiteFolder/
  - index.html
  - images/
    - eye.jpg
```

2. Put Pictures in HTML:

In your web page (usually named "index.html" or something similar), you can use a special code called an  tag to show a picture. But, you need to tell it where to find the picture.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Your Website</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome to My Website</h1>
    <img src="images/eye.jpg" alt="Eye Image">
</body>
</html>
```

In the  tag, you put the path to your picture. It's like telling your web page, "Hey, look in the 'images' folder and find 'eye.jpg'."
Check Picture Names and Types:

Make sure the picture on your desktop is named exactly "eye.jpg" and that it has the right file type, like ".jpg" (all lowercase, not ".JPG").
If you do these steps right, your picture should show up on your website when you open your web page in a web browser. If it doesn't, just double-check that your folders and picture names match what you wrote in your web page.

Comment: Hey thanks for replying, yeah when i coding on vs it worked before, but rn i am editing on a website called dash from General assembly. and i cant add a image to a directory... dash.generalassemb.ly/projects this is the website

Comment: provide some snippet so you will get a better result

Comment: Are you building your website while connected to the internet or without an internet connection? If you're online, it's best to host your images on servers rather than storing them on your desktop. If you're offline, make sure to copy the images to the same location as your HTML files before attempting to use them.

Comment: Yes i am connected to the internet, how would i host an imagine in a server?